# Got "'d3' is undefined" error when I remotely access my server in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, d3.js

With Internet Explorer v11, I got "'d3' is undefined" error when I accessed to my d3 web site which was deployed in remote IIS7 server.
However, with Internet Explorer v11, there was no this "'d3' is undefined" error when I accessed to my d3 web site which was deployed in my local IIS7 server.

And, with Firefox and Chrome, there was no this "'d3' is undefined" error when I accessed to my d3 web site which was deployed in my both remote and local IIS7 server.

That is, on my local server with "localhost", my d3 website works fine. But, when I tried to access the server from remote computer, I got this "'d3' is undefined" error. This issue only happens in IE, not in Firefox and Chrome.

I have tried the following ways, but this issue still exists.

```
< meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" >   
< script src="JavaScript/d3.v3.min.js"  charset="utf-8 >< /script >  
< script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8" >< /script >
```

Then I found that this issue was caused by this code in d3.v3.js:

```
......try {
  d3_document.createElement("DIV").style.setProperty("opacity", 0, "");
} catch (error) {
  var d3_element_prototype = this.Element.prototype, d3_element_setAttribute = d3_element_prototype.setAttribute, ......
```

This code create the error "Object doesn't support property or method 'setProperty" because d3_document.createElement("DIV").style doesn't have setProperty() in IE11 with .NET Framework 3.5

But how to fix this? Can anyone help me? This issue have bothered me several days.
Many many thanks.

Greg.

Comment: what is error in console ? why there is space between angle bracket and s?  `< s`

Comment: I have found that this issue was caused by this code in d3.v3.min.js: 
......}catch(ha){var ga=this.Element.prototype,pa=ga.setAttribute,va=ga.setAttributeNS,......
This code throw the error "Unable to get property 'prototype' of undefined or null reference" because this.Element is null

Comment: Ohh. If you have resolved you can answer you own question and close it. Also you can raise the issue in the d3js source- https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues

Comment: Please ignore the space between angle bracket and s.

Comment: This issue is still not fixed.

Comment: Please post your all code or make a working fiddle